# Passing two variables as string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I get an error in html page for javascript 
I am trying to pass string variables in function 
PFB the code

```
document.write('<input type = "submit" value = "Details" class = "myButton" onClick = "dealerDetailsService(\''+orderDate+'\,\''+dealerCode+'\')"></input>');
```

gives error

```
Expected ')'
```

Comment: On side note. Never Ever use document.write. There's absolutely no way it cannot be removed from the code

Comment: Color formatting is your friend here, aswell as the pretty clear error message...

Comment: I am using simple html pages ... no eclipse does phonegap have eclipse plugin too

Comment: I need to make this as app in mobile using phonegap ... how can I do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgotten a `'` after the first argument:

```
document.write('<input type="submit" value="Details" 
                   class="myButton" 
                   onClick="dealerDetailsService(\''+orderDate+'\',\''+dealerCode+'\')" />'); 
                                                                 ^ here
```